# A word to say 'I work' but for leisure

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs

I'm a Software Engineer and I like to spend my free time developing new software/ideas.
When people ask me what I've done this weekend, I typically reply 'I worked'.

'Work' is misleading here as it is automatically associated with professional work.

I'd like to find a word (a verb) that could mention that I worked during my weekend but for leisure, not as a constraint, and whatever the underlying discipline. Like when the painter said 'I paint', we automatically know that is for pleasure.

I hope to be clear enough...

Comment: It would depend entirely on the nature of the work. **Exercised**, **created**, **played**, **laboured**, and so on, are all possible. Also, it's *not* automatically known that somebody who paints does so only for pleasure—nor would doing it for pleasure exclude the fact that it involved work.

Comment: *Experiment* is another possibility.

Comment: "To work "on* something" can give the impression that the activity wasn't necessarily a formal job. You could add "my own" to emphasize this, e.g., *Last weekend I worked on some of my own software ideas.*